# XML, reading attributes to an object, VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to get the price out (90.0) of this xml document but get it to work, i've tried using the xmlTextReader and the ReadElementString function but I guess I need to get the attribute. I then looked at using the GetAttribute function.

```
<s:inventories>
- <s:inventory channel="online" availability="inStock">
  <s:price currency="USD">90.0</s:price> 
  </s:inventory>
  </s:inventories>
```

I'm sure its easy enough but can't find online how do accomplish this, any ideas anyone?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim xmlString as String = ...

Dim s As XNamespace = "s"
Dim e As XElement = XElement.Parse(xmlString)
Dim price = e.Element(s + "inventory").Element(s + "price").Value
```

Just make sure you declare namespace for `"s"`.

Comment: Thanks for that but when I just tried this I get a null reference error on the last line? "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Comment: Can you post how you include the declared namespace? Without namespace, this snippet http://pastie.org/2532997 will print 90.0

Comment: That does work, cheers. For the full xmlstring though it falls over:

Comment: I can't seem to be able to add the full Xml string into this website on the page, can you email me at paul.standage@gmail.com and I can send it over?